# Polygon following arithmetic sequence

Tags: geometry, polygons, arithmetic-progressions

I was reading a chapter arithmetic sequence ,then I came up across a question"***the difference between any two consecutive interior angles of a polygon is 5° where smallest angle is 120°.Find the number of the sides of the polygon***".But I could be able to solve this question.But my main doubt is which are the polygon which follows arithmetic sequence? Explain with the help of diagram.

Note that the angles are increasing arithmetically by 5°

Comment: What is your main doubt answer to this problem or want to know polyogons which follow ap in their angles

Comment: Yes I want to know the polygons diagrammatically

Comment: Assume the polygon is convex, the polygon will have $9$ sides and the exterior angles will be $60^\circ, 55^\circ, 50^\circ,\ldots, 20^\circ$. On the circumference of a unit circle centered at $O$, take points $A, B, C,\ldots,I$ such that $\angle AOB = 60^\circ, \angle BOC = 55^\circ, \ldots, \angle IOA = 20^\circ$ and construct tangent lines at these points. The nonagon bounded by these $9$ tangent lines will have the interior angles you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: use the formula for the sum of interior angles of a polygon, and the formula for the sum of a finite arithmetic series.

Comment: Can you do and show

Comment: I can do it, and have two solutions, but have two concerns: (1) this is your homework, and you have shown no effort; (2) the solutions are somewhat inconsistent with the description that "the difference between any two consecutive interior angles is 5 degrees", as this statement seems to imply that the angle "before" the starting angle is 125 degrees. My solutions allow the angles to grow by 5 degrees at each vertex, until reaching a maximum, and then the next angle is the starting angle = 120 degrees.

Comment: This is not my homework question it's a doubt which I come across

Answer (score 0):

Sum of all angles of a polygon.

> $=$$(n-2)180$

Sum of all terms of AP

> $=$$\dfrac n2 \big[2a + (n-1)d\big]$

Now you know the first term that is $120$ and common difference $5$.

> Note the equation will give two answers $16$ and $9$ but the answer $16$ wont satisfy think why?
>
> Because if a polygon has $16$ sides with the smallest angle $120°$ then one angle will be $180°$ (following the given conditiona of question) thus $180°$ means a straight line.(not an angle to be considered)